# How to upload VMware esx VM to Azure without any base image?

Tags: azure, vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

We have some machines at our local esx servers. Which contain many configurations done manually and takes time to convert them to any ansible or other configuration. So, any option to upload them as is to azure as custom images?

I saw few posts but those are built on existing images of azure.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of options. I would agree the rebuilding OS in cloud from scratch would be preferable. Worth mentioning, I've tested StarWind V2V to convert my local VMs to Azure recently. Worked nice, might be useful:
https://www.starwindsoftware.com/v2v-help/ConvertingtoMicrosoftAzure.html

Answer (score 2):

Several variants of how to upload VMs to Azure. [Convert disks to VHD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/prepare-for-upload-vhd-image#convert-from-vmware-vmdk-disk-format) and [upload into Azure disks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/upload-generalized-managed) yourself. Or use [Azure Migrate with VMware integration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/tutorial-prepare-vmware) and have a tool help you do it.

---

Reconsider investing time in automating configuration from clean OS images. This gives you the maximum flexibility in rebuilding from scratch. Enables enforcing desired configuration, easier OS upgrades, portability in moving to different hypervisors, and a recovery option if your VM disk image backups are lost.